# Minimizing and Maximizing Windows With VBscript or Batch files

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I'm trying to find a way to maximize & minimize a certain application using vbscript or a batch file. I've seen multiple attempts at doing this but none of them seem to work. Does anybody have any suggestions, without having to download any third party software.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm looking for a way to do this after the program is already running.

Comment: You can maximize & minimize the window in a Batch file, you just need to copy three small files in a couple minutes: [Window.exe](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428&p=17216#p17216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that /MIN and /MAX switches of START command should work, that is:

```
START "Window Title" /MAX YourApplication Parameters ...
```

Type `START /?` for further details.

Comment: I was looking for commands that would do this after an application is already running. This doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Then you should add this to your question, as it's not obvious

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to maximize the batch window, you can use the code

```
Mode Con Cols=500 Lines=500
```

what this does is determine how many text blocks up and down there are, for example, if you changed cols to 20, you could fit twenty letters in that window.  And Lines are the same way, but going up and down.

:edit
sorry, I read your question wrong.  either way, my answer was wrong. I think the only way is to maximize it from startup.